# git - use a feature branch, started from a very old commit, as the new master branch going forward

Tags: git, merge

Previously, before the 'feature' branch existed, the master branch was the only branch, with 150 commits done on it over time:

```
master: 001--002--003--...--150
```

We decided to make a new feature branch, but we needed to start it from a much earlier point in the master branch:

```
feature:        151
               /
master: 001--002--003--...--150
```

We completed work on the feature branch; no work has been done on master in the meantime:

```
feature:        151--152--...--160
               /
master: 001--002--003--...--150
```

We've determined that all work on master since that branch point needs to be put aside (but preserved, hopefully without changing the commit IDs), and the completed feature branch needs to be the new master branch going forward.  So we are basically looking for something like this:

```
feature:        151--152--...--160
               /                  \
master: 001--002--003--...--150   161
```

The path to get from 150 to 161 isn't relevant - we could draw a brick wall between 150 and 161 to illustrate it more clearly.  We are basically redoing the whole content of the master branch.  However, we definitely want to preserve 003 thru 150 for future reference.

An alternative structure going forward might look like:

```
master:   001--002--151--152--...--160 (or 161)

sidebar: 001--002--003--...--150
   or
sidebar: 002--003--...--150
```

Either way, the goal is for 160 (or 161) to be the head of master, and for the history of 001--002--003--...--150 to be preserved for reference.

Should this be done with a simple merge command or is there more to it?  I've been reading docs (rebase? merge -s ours? other?) and googling around for a few days, but I'm not experienced enough with git to be able to interpret things.

Comment: Why don't you just rename `feature` -> `master` and `master` -> (for example) `master-backup`?

Comment: Yeah, what jonrsharpe said. Why not just do the simple obvious thing?